# How to dismiss a UIAlert with no buttons or interaction in Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit

I am using a UIAlert to display the string "Loading..." while my iOS application is interacting with a database. Is there any way to pragmatically dismiss it when the action is complete?
code:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.test.org/ios.html")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        if error != nil {
             print("Error: \(error)")
        } 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
            // dismiss sendLoading() UIAlert
        }
    }
}
task.resume() 
self.sendLoading()
```

sendLoading func:

```
func sendLoading() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Loading...", message:
            "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785715/how-to-display-an-activity-indicator-with-text-on-ios-8-with-swift ? Look up Activity Indicator Swift as well.

Comment: This seems like a very jarring, non-intuitive way to show database activity (which is probably a regular occurrence in an app lifecycle). Alerts imply that immediate action or attention is needed from the user. The alternatives from @lukeslvi look promising.

Answer (score 0):

Make your alertController as instance variable and when you need to dismiss it just call

```
self.dismissViewController(alertController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Edit - Adding code.
In your case code would be like -

```
  let alertController : UIAlertController ?
  let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.test.org/ios.html")
  let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
  request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
  let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
data, response, error in
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    if error != nil {
         print("Error: \(error)")
    } 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
        // dismiss sendLoading() UIAlert
      self.dismissViewController(alertController!, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
task.resume() 
self.sendLoading()
```

sendLoading func:

```
func sendLoading() {
alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Loading...", message:
        "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `UIAlertController` have the function `dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)` that according to Apple:

> Dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the view controller.

Then what you need to do is to keep a reference to the `UIAlertController` as a property in your `UIViewController` and then dismiss it as you like, something like this:

```
// instance of the UIAlertController to dismiss later 
var alertController: UIAlertController!

func sendLoading() {
    self.alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Loading...", message:
        "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.test.org/ios.html")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
   data, response, error in
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
       let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       if error != nil {
            print("Error: \(error)")
       } 
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
           self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
           // dismiss sendLoading() UIAlert
           self.alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
       }
   }
}
task.resume() 
self.sendLoading()
```

I hope this help you.