# Xcode Display a loading view until the second view loads (on a segue show)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, view, segue

I have an app that switch views using a segue when a button is clicked.
The second view loads data from the internet and it can take a couple of seconds.
I would like to know how can i display a loading view/splash screen in the meantime so the view could finish the loading and the app wont appear like it's doing nothing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this library [SwiftSpinner](https://github.com/icanzilb/SwiftSpinner). It serves the purpose of your needs. It's really brilliant.

Call the necessary function from the library in the `viewDidLoad` method of your `ViewController` which loads the data from the internet. Remove this view in `DidFinishLoading` method of the `NSURLProtocol` (It's an optional func declared in that class which detects when the request to that URL is complete). The documentation is given in that library itself.

Comment: Thanks, this did the job

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for an activity indicator. I've used the custom class posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/32661590/3516923 with success. Just a note of warning, in his class he blocks all input while the indicator is in view. If you want to make it so your users can back out before things finish you need to remove `UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()` and `UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()` from the start and stop animating functions.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is really a splash screen, have a UIImageView underneath the view that you're loading.  Set the image to your splash screen image.  Set the loading view to hidden=YES before it's shown, then set hidden to NO after it finishes loading.  You could even set the opacity of the frontmost view to give you a fading effect.

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to find a kind of indicator, suck like an activity indicator or something else to show the loading UI to the user.
2.Set the user interaction unable, so that the user won`t touchup inside repeatedly.
3.Start the indicator, set the user interaction unable when you load the server data, and stop the indicator animation when you finish, hide the indicator, enabled the user interaction.