# How to create Activity Indicator View?

Tags: swift, indicator

Would you please advice me how to create an  Activity Indicator View?
I have a normal button:

```
@IBAction func NextViewController(sender: AnyObject) {


}
```

it takes lots of time until my app loads the next view controller and I would like to have a normal indicator which will inform the users to wait a bit.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785715/how-to-display-an-activity-indicator-with-text-on-ios-8-with-swift

Comment: Thank you, but it does not help me:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can advice you to use the [LilithProgressHUD](https://github.com/Liquicit/LilithProgressHUD). It's the best Activity Indicator View I have ever used.

[image]

Install it with `pod 'LilithProgressHUD'`.

```
//Import LilithProgressHUD
import LilithProgressHUD

//Show the HUD
LilithProgressHUD.show()

//Hide the HUD
LilithProgressHUD.hide()
```

That is literally it...

So in your example:

```
@IBAction func NextViewController(sender: AnyObject) {

     LilithProgressHUD.show()
}
```

That would be it... At the `NextViewController` viewDidLoad you would then call `LilithProgressHUD.hide()`.

Also. I have set the properties of the view within my AppDelegate.

```
LilithProgressHUD.size = (self.window?.frame.size.height)! // sets the size to the size of my App
LilithProgressHUD.opacity = 0.75 // sets the opacity nice to a value where you can slightly see the App
```

Comment: hey would you please tell me where can I download this LilithProgressHUD.swift I cant find it

Comment: here is the github link

Comment: i recommend you install it via cocoapods. then you can update easily to newer versions

Comment: Yes I downloaded the whole project but I cant find .swift file :(

Comment: I am beginner I will need some help can I text you in the chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124027/discussion-between-david-seek-and-dakata).

Comment: Yes I see it is working, but it is not working properly. When I click the button it still wait 1-2 seconds and when it loads the next view contoroller then it starts working. Any ideas how to fix it, I want to start loading it as soon as I press the button

Comment: here it's perfectly working. like really perfectly. the HUD appears immediately.

Comment: i think you should close this thread. checkmark my answer please since it's solved. and then you open up a new question with "why is there the time lack blah blah" and provide some code. then we can try to fix this

Comment: otherwise this thread might become too confusing/unclear for following readers